# Connecting To Firestore Using Laravel 6 Not Working

Tags: php, laravel, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, laravel-6

I've been trying to insert data into firestore using my laravel 6 application and it looks like its trying to connect to mysql.

I've tried to remove the db part in my .env file:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=laravel
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

But it doesnt seem to work.
First off this is the error am getting when i try to insert:

```
"message": "SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

This is my php code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Google\Cloud\Firestore\FirestoreClient;
use Google\Cloud\Firestore\FireStoreDocument;

class LogisticsController extends Controller
{

    public $firestoreClient;

    /**
     * __construct initialize firestore client
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {

        $this->firestoreClient = new FirestoreClient([
            'projectId' => 'my-project-id',
        ]);

    }

    /**
     * create  a new logistics company
     *
     * @return 
     */
    protected function create(Request $request)
    {

        //get and validate form data
        $validatedData = $request->validate([
            'company_name' => 'required|unique:company_name|max:255',
            'registration_no' => 'required'
        ]);

        $company_name = $request->company_name;
        $registration_no = $request->registration_no;

        $this->firestoreClient->addDocument('Logistics_Companies', [
            'company_name' =>  $company_name,
            'registration_no' => $registration_no,
            'created_at' => new FirestoreTimestamp,
            'updated_at' => '',
            'deleted_at' => ''  
        ]);
    } 
}
```

I dont know why its trying to connect using mysql. Anyone know what i need to do or what am doing wrong ???.

Every form of help is highly appreciated. Cheers!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The env file is only used to override the default database defined in the config/databases.php file, within that file you'll need to modify this line if you don't want to use mysql:

```
'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql')
```

However, since it's trying to connect to a mysql database, somewhere in your project you're using Laravel's orm (eloquent) and will need to integrate Firestore at a deeper level into Laravel or refrain from using Eloquent.